# 'multiple definition of __vector_11’ arduino compiling problem with RH_ASK.h and PulseSensorPlayground.h

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm working on a project sending data got by pulse sensor from a 433 transmitter to a receiver.
Here are my codes.

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>
#define PULSENSORPIN A0

PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;
RH_ASK transmitter;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  transmitter.init();
  pulseSensor.analogInput(PULSENSORPIN);
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(550);
  pulseSensor.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  int myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();
  String str_myBPM = String(myBPM);
  const char *msg = str_myBPM.c_str();
  transmitter.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
  transmitter.waitPacketSent();
}
```

I got problems when compiling and got this issue:

```
C:\Users\Helen474402\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\E400C37EF824CAD4EB4682519060B7A8\libraries\RadioHead\RH_ASK.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `RH_ASK::maxMessageLength()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_11'
C:\Users\Helen474402\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\E400C37EF824CAD4EB4682519060B7A8\sketch\Transmitter.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

My board: Arduino nano
Arduino IDE version: 2.1.0

Both RH_ASK library and Pulsesensor library are installed in Arduino, should be the latest version.

I don't quite know how to fix the error that comes up and so any assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: i think 2 of your libraries are using the same timer (timer 2 i believe). I would remove some of the functionality until it works, so you know which libraries are conflicting, and then see if you can specify which timer to use for the library so you can choose a different one

Comment: Try adding #define Servo_h before the inclusion of the PulseSensorPlayground.h   That should force it to use timer2 instead of timer1 because it thinks you're using the Servo library.